# How to make this average of positions?

Tags: java, android

I have list with multiple choice. Application must calculate the average of whole list's positions.

In first activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {

Button button_1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    button_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
    button_1.setOnClickListener(this);


}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_1:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
}
}
```

In second activity each position must have int variable ( Uruguay - 3444000, Paraguay - 6725000 e.t.c) In result, in third activity must be displayed average of each position.

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button2
```

\button2 direct to third activity

```
String[] countries = { "Urugay", "Paraguay", "Jamaica", "Peru", "Mexico"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView countriesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.countriesList);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, countries);

    countriesList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

The countries displayed in second activity without variables. But after picked by user, average displayed in third activity.

Need your advice, Or some code )

Answer (score 0):

Just like this array:

```
String[] countries = { "Urugay", "Paraguay", "Jamaica", "Peru", "Mexico"};
```

create another one:

```
int[] positions = {  3444000, 6725000, 0, 0, 0};
```

then with a loop you find the average:

```
int sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
    sum += positions[i];
}
int average = sum / positions.length;
```

Comment: parallel arrays are typically considered a poor design. try a map

Comment: @PatrickParker you mean I should suggest to somebody who does not know how to calculate an average to use a map?

Comment: @PatrickParker I'm sure he will read your comment and consider it.

Comment: if you think it may be too complex, it should at least be a footnote. this is Java not QBasic, so might as well show the proper Java way of doing it then.

Comment: @mTak 1, The countries displayed in second activity without variables. But after picked by user, average displayed in third activity.

Comment: @PatrickParker You can post it as an answer. I leave it up to you,

Comment: @Ahillesius you can use the above code in any activity you want and after the calculation of the average, pass the value to the next activity as an extra value in the intent

Comment: @mTak 1, In your advise app has two arrays (string and int types), but they has't corralation

Comment: @Ahillesius How else would you calculate an average without numbers?

Comment: @mTak, I mean how to make relation with string array(which is displayed) and int array ( which is just in code). The user must pick the countries, to pick the button2, and after in thied actrivity displayed average

Comment: @Ahillesius the 1st element of the array corresponds to the 1st element of the other and so on

Answer (score 0):

Is it that you need to calculate the average? You do that by adding all the points an divide them by the number of entries. So in this case, add the points of the two countries an divide them by two.
Keep in mind that dividing mostly has a result with a fraction (something behind the decimal point), so be sure to get a floating point type variable and, if needed, round appropriately to an int afterwards.

Comment: Meanwhile, it might indeed be a good idea to look at map. There are plenty examples abound. For instance https://www.javatpoint.com/java-map